# ffmpeg - combining multiple images and multiple audio files?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to create a video out of two images `figure1.png` and `figure2.png` (which may be of different sizes) and two audio files `audio1.wav` and `audio2.wav`. I want to do it such that `figure1.png` shows until `audio1.wav` stops playing and then `figure2.png` shows until `audio2.wav` stops playing (with audio2.wav starting after audio1.wav). I am having no real luck doing this. My best attempt so far is to create two videos and try and merge them but due to formating issues this does not seem to work. I was therefore wondering is there was a way to do this with a single ffmpeg command and if so what?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say the size of the first image is larger and is WxH. If not scale down the 2nd size and then pad. Either way, both images should have the same size.

```
ffmpeg -i image1.png -i image2.png -i audio1.wav -i audio2.wav
  -filter_complex
     "[0]setsar=1[a];
      [1]pad=W:H:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:color=white,setsar=1[b];
      [2]abitscope=r=25:s=WxH[a1v]; 
      [3]abitscope=r=25:s=WxH[a2v];
      [a1v][a]overlay[v1];
      [a2v][b]overlay[v2];
      [v1][2:a][v2][3:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1"  out.mp4
```

Comment: Hi Mulvya this looks like it should work but I am getting an error:  `[AVFilterGraph @ 0x2317500] No output pad can be associated to link label '1'.
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument` Any ideas?

Comment: Missed a semicolon; added.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, I am now getting the error `No such filter: 'abitscope'` I can't seem to find how to download/install this filter - do you know how I can get it?

Comment: Use a very recent build.

Comment: I am using linux (mint) and I appear to have the most recent version, I have also tried downloading libavfilter-dev but I still get this error.

Comment: Show the banner of your build.

Comment: I am assuming this is what you mean: `ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers...`? (by the way thanks for your help it is much appreciated)

Comment: That's a very old version. As far as ffmpeg is concerned, never use the release builds if you can help it. Always git builds.

Answer (score 1):

You should first create the video without audio i guess. To do that:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i figure%01d.png output.mp4
```

%01d is the pattern of your png file names. I assume mp4 container format will be suitable.

After that, according to the duration of your audio files (you should adjust calculate them manually, there is no automatic fitting mechanism as far as i know).

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i figure%01d.png -i audio.wav -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -shortest out.mp4
```

Here internal AAC encoder is used but you can use any other AAC encoding mechanism as well.